# Change Css Class of Same Id which is more than one Id with same name in html page

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to change css class for same id which is appear more than one in page. i try but when there is 2 id with same name reflect only first id not for other.

### i try:

view page :
`<i id="{{obj.id}}"></i>`

Controller

`$(getJson.Id).removeClass('busy b-white bottom');`

`$(getJson.Id).addClass('on b-white bottom');`

so, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: ***ID should always be unique*** Use class and index instead.

Comment: ... use class instead.

Comment: use 2 different id for 2 event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

► First of all Id must be unique.

When ever you are using Id with the same name , try to use class instead of that.

Your solution will be something like

```
$('[id='+getJson.Id+']').removeClass('busy b-white bottom').addClass('on b-white bottom');
```

This is a simple method tho select all elements with same id.

```js
$('[id=test]').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red')
```

```css
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test" class="yellow">q</p>
<p id="test" class="yellow">w</p>
<p id="test" class="yellow">e</p>
```

Comment: @MiteshMachhi always glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Like said an **ID should always be unique**, but if you doesn't want to take an advice, you can select all matched id using attribute selector(**not recommended as ID must be unique**) :

```
$('[id='+getJson.Id+']').removeClass('busy b-white bottom');
$('[id='+getJson.Id+']').addClass('on b-white bottom');
```